# Pandas, every x row depending on value of other row

Tags: pandas

I have a data set with values that are both parent and child in different rows. The ID format is slightly different between a parent and a child, so I should be able to identify them with regex.

So the structure is something like this

```
Parent ID | Other data
Child ID | Other data
Child ID | Other data
Child ID | Other data
Parent ID | Other data
Child ID | Other data
Parent ID | Other data
Child ID | Other data
Child ID | Other data
Child ID | Other data
```

There are no set amount of children, but the only thing that is always true is that a parent will come first then it's children, then the next parent and it's children, and so forth.

I am not sure how to identify this. Ideally, I'd be able to traverse the rows, and tag all the children with the parent's ID in a different (new) row.

It's not a great structure, but it comes like this from the data source.

I'd like an output like this

```
Parent ID | Other data
Child ID | Other data | Parent ID
Child ID | Other data | Parent ID
Child ID | Other data | Parent ID
Parent ID | Other data | 
Child ID | Other data | Parent ID
Parent ID | Other data |
Child ID | Other data | Parent ID
Child ID | Other data | Parent ID
Child ID | Other data | Parent ID
```

So the whole file, thousands of rows, follow this format, where a parent is listed first, all it's children, then the next parent.

Comment: kindly post ur expected output. helps to fully understand ur question

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, I edited the post.

Comment: it might be an issue. kindly put some numbers or different values for the different parent ids

Comment: Sure, Parent ID: 9843112356, Child 7744321, so the formats are different, and I should be able to identify them with regex or other logic -- the main problem is the logic of traversing the data frame and tag them correctly.

I.e. if I'd do a for loop. I'd start with row 1 as parent and until a new parent is reached, I'd tag each child. Then when a new parent shows up, I'd do the same, and repeat until done.

Comment: nah, i dont think u need to do it row wise. u can use pandas' vectorized methods. just change up a couple of lines for ur data(fake numbers are fine, not the generic parent id and child), and i or someone else should be able to give u a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do so with `ffill` and some masking

```
# identify all parents
# replace with your regex
patt = '(Parent)'
is_parent = df['ID'].str.extract(patt).notnull()[0]

# ids:
df['parent_ID'] = df['ID'].where(is_parent).ffill().mask(is_parent)
```

Output:

```
          ID        data   ParentID
0  Parent ID  Other data        NaN
1   Child ID  Other data  Parent ID
2   Child ID  Other data  Parent ID
3   Child ID  Other data  Parent ID
4  Parent ID  Other data        NaN
5   Child ID  Other data  Parent ID
6  Parent ID  Other data        NaN
7   Child ID  Other data  Parent ID
8   Child ID  Other data  Parent ID
9   Child ID  Other data  Parent ID
```